# all values not coming while parsing json to string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i have j son data in string in j son response. I'm able to get only request-id value. other are coming in debugging but unable to retrieve from dictionary type.can u tell me how to get other values of a mobile number- date , status and description.
screen shot added kindly go through it http://postimg.org/image/6iad15yxl/

my j son data

```
{
    "requestId": "546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567",
    "numbers": {
        "917566551111": {
            "date": "2014-11-18 17:45:59",
            "status": 1,
            "desc": "DELIVERED"
        }
    }
}
```

C# code

```
        public partial class jsontoCsharp : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

        json = Request.QueryString["data"];

                var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
                 string requestid = req.requestId;
                  }
        }

   public class smsstatus
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}


public class Request
{
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, smsstatus> numbers { get; set; } //<-- See this line
}
```

Comment: your class is not matched with the json

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be something like this

```
public class smsstatus
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}


public class Request
{
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, smsstatus> numbers { get; set; } //<-- See this line
}
```

Now these deserializations will work

```
var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
```

or

```
var req = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Request>(json);
```

Comment: @krishnamohan Enumerate dictionary. *Key* is the number, other values are in *Value*. (put a breakpoint in your code and see the debuggers output)

Comment: hi...can u tell me how to get other values? number, status , description ???
http://postimg.org/image/6iad15yxl/
these are my values@ezi

Comment: @krishnamohan If you can't get the values from a `Dictionary<string, smsstatus>`, then forget my answer and start to read C# docs... I though you have a basic knowledge about collections in c#.

Answer (score 0):

As your Json is quite complex, try as following..

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

`var result` is containing your deserialized json now you can access the `results` object using dot (.) notation

Comment: i cannot use dynamic because its 3.5 frame work @gypsyCoder

Comment: oops... ok then it'll not work for you @krishnamohan